# Showing uniqueness of solution to IVP under certain conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $\mathbf{\dot x} = f(\mathbf{x},t)$ where $\mathbf{x}(0) = 0$, $f$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $(x,t) = (0,0)$ and $|f(x,t)-f(y,t)| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{t^\alpha}$.  I would like to show the uniquenesss of the solution if $\alpha\in (0,1)$.

It seems like I would like to show that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$ when $t = 0$ if $\alpha\in(0,1)$, (since it is clearly locally Lipschitz for all $t > 0$) but I haven't been able to tackle that by elementary methods (or any other, really).  Another idea might be to bound the sequence of Picard iterates, but that seems very messy.  A third idea would be to appeal to general facts about moduli of continuity.  The fact that a solution is unique when the integral $\int_0^x\frac{dx}{\omega(x)}$ diverges for the modulus $\omega$ seems almost useful, except that in this case my modulus is a function of both $x$ and $t$.  Am I in the right ballpark with these approaches, or is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Also, this is homework, so I would be grateful for a small hint rather than a full solution.  Thanks in advance!